# In MOSFET switching loss calculation, where does the 0.5 factor come from?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, buck, switching-losses

I am going through this material for calculating the switching loss of the mosfet.(https://www.monolithicpower.com/frequency-selection-in-switching-power-supply-designs-part-i)

The switching loss equation given in the material is

[image]

I understood everything except the (1/2) term. May I know from where this 0.5 comes in this equation.

Comment: While the FET is switching, the voltage across it rises about linearly from Vin to 0, or back again. Plot it, you'll see a triangle tRise (or tFall) long, and Vin high. The area of that triangle is half that of a rectangle tRise * Vin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The turn-off or turn-on losses can be computed in different ways depending on the adopting scenario. When the first scenario assumes a triangle waveform, then there is a factor of 0.5 which is factored since the area is half of the rectangle shown in the below picture:

[image]

As shown in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071823468), the second scenario is when the crossing of the two waveforms occurs in the middle of the slopes. In this case, there is a 1/6 coefficient.

Comment: ,Thank you.I have that book but finished only 1st two chapters.

Comment: Glad to count you among my readers! : )